# Updating TextViews live as you type in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I'm trying to programme an Android app that will update some TextViews as I enter some values into some EditText views (live updating). I thought maybe using a while loop in some form might help but I wondered if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a beter way. Just use :

```
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){...}
```

And use the `onTextChanged(...)` function from the textwatcher in order to modify the content of your label.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for, marked it as the correct answer. I would vote up but I don't have 15 reputation lol.